# Kibana FATAL Error: [elasticsearch.url]: definition for this key is missing

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

install and start was ok on a ubuntu 18.04 for kibana but I find this

```
FATAL  Error: [elasticsearch.url]: definition for this key is missing
```

in /var/log/kibana/kibana.stderr

I have this

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: "192.168.56.51"
elasticsearch.url: http://localhost:9201
```

in /etc/kibana/kibana.yml
and when I do a wget http://localhost:9201 on the machine I get the expected index.html

any obvious reason why kibana could complain ?

[Update]
meantime I have reinstalled the whole installation and it works for some reason. Howerever in many forums peaple has the same issue, so there might be a pitfallduring the installation.

Answer (score 13):

I got the same issue for 7.2.0, got resolved by

elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200/"]

#elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200"

Comment: This is correct: 
`elasticsearch.url is no longer valid`

From [Breaking changes in 7.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#_elasticsearch_url_is_no_longer_valid):

Answer (score 6):

Try using this instead of "elasticsearch.url: http://localhost:9201":

```
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200/"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Unfortunatetly that didn't hel. I also uses the ipadress with no success. Sorry for the late reply I only have the environment a few days per week